# Integral of absolute value = absolute value of the integral

Tags: integration, absolute-value

Let $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $f \in C^0([a, b] , \mathbb{C})$
Find the condition on $f$ so that
$$|\int_a^b f|=\int_a^b|f|$$

**My try :**
The function $f: t \mapsto r(t)\exp(i\theta)$ where $r$ is a positive real value function and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the equation and I think it's the best shot we can get, but I'm not 100% sure.
Besides, I've no idea where to start.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Collateral classroom reading: Thomas Elliot Mott, [*Equality in* $\left| \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx \right| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)| dx$](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2313202), **American Mathematical Monthly** 69 #10 (December 1962), 996-998.

Comment: Thanks for the reference ! It looks like a good place to improve my skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost right: $r$ need not be positive, it suffices that $r$ is nonnegative. It is straightforwart to show that for such a function bot sides evaluate to $\int_a^br(t)\,\mathrm dt$.

Now assume that $f$ is *not* of this form. Show that for arbitrary $\theta$, $$ \int_a^b\Re (e^{-i\theta}f(t))\,\mathrm dt<\int_a^b|f(t)|\,\mathrm dt$$
because there is always some open interval where $f$ strictly deviates from being a nonegative multiple of $e^{i\theta}$ and hence where $\Re (e^{-i\theta}f(t))<|f(t)|$.

Comment: Exactly what I needed ;) Thanks a lot