# Absolute value of an integral

Tags: calculus

Question: Let $f(x)\in C^1[a,b]$ and $f(x)\neq 0$ in $a\leq x\leq b$, then $$\left|\int_{a}^b f(x) dx\right|=  \int_{a}^b |f(x)| dx  \tag{1}$$

My views: We have $$\left|\int_{a}^b f(x) dx\right|\leq  \int_{a}^b |f(x)| dx  $$
Now $f(x)\neq 0$ in $a\leq x\leq b$, so we have either $f(x)>0$ in $a\leq x\leq b$ or $f(x)<0$ in $a\leq x\leq b$.

Then we have the equality as given in $(1)$. How to use the fact that $f(x)\in C^1[a,b]$?

Comment: "so we have either $f(x) > 0$ ... or $f(x) < 0$".  What theorem/property of $f$ are you using for that?

Comment: @Eric Towers Sorry. It was just a guess.

Comment: @Harry It is correct. Use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @Mason Is the result also true for complex valued function?

Comment: @Harry, For your question in the last comment, how about $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{ix}\,\mathrm{d}x=0 \ ?$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes it is but what is the condition that it holds?

Comment: @Sangchul Lee see here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808658/integral-of-absolute-value-absolute-value-of-the-integral

Comment: Yes, the equality holds if and only if $f(x)=\alpha|f(x)|$ on $[a,b]$ for some constant $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$. But I think this is not what exactly you asked in your last comment...

Comment: @Sangchul Lee Please prove your last comment

Answer (score 3):

Based on OP's request, let me prove a more general claim:

> **Theorem.** Let $\mathbf{f} : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be continuous. Then the followings are equivalent:
>
> 1. $ \left\| \int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{f}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right\| = \int_{a}^{b} \| \mathbf{f}(x) \| \, \mathrm{d}x $
> 2. $\mathbf{f}(x) = \| \mathbf{f}(x) \| \mathbf{u}$ for some $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $\|\mathbf{u}\| = 1$.

$(1)\impliedby(2)$ : Suppose (2) holds. Then

$$ \left\| \int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{f}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right\|
= \left\| \left( \int_{a}^{b} \| \mathbf{f}(x) \| \, \mathrm{d}x \right) \mathbf{u} \right\|
= \left( \int_{a}^{b} \| \mathbf{f}(x) \| \, \mathrm{d}x \right) \left\| \mathbf{u} \right\|
= \int_{a}^{b} \| \mathbf{f}(x) \| \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

$(1) \implies (2)$ :

*Case 1.* If $\int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{f}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=\mathbf{0}$, then (1) implies $\int_{a}^{b} \| \mathbf{f}(x) \| \, \mathrm{d}x = 0$. Being an integral of a continuous function, this implies that $\|\mathbf{f}(x)\|$ is identically zero. Then the same is true for $\mathbf{f}(x)$, and so, any unit vector $\mathbf{u}$ will work.

*Case 2.* Now suppose $\int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{f}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \neq \mathbf{0}$. Let $\mathbf{u} = \left(\int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{f}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x\right)/\left\|\int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{f}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x\right\|$. Then

$$
\left\| \int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{f}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right\|
= \mathbf{u} \cdot \left( \int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{f}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right)
= \int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{f}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x, $$

and so, the equality (1) implies that

$$ \int_{a}^{b} (\| \mathbf{f}(x) \| - \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{f}(x)) \, \mathrm{d}x = 0. $$

However, Cauchy–Schwarz inequality shows that the integrand $\| \mathbf{f}(x) \| - \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{f}(x)$ is always non-negative. So it follows that $\| \mathbf{f}(x) \| - \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{f}(x) = 0$ identically on $[a, b]$ and therefore the claim is proved.